# how to access access in javascript in ArrayList<Object> converted to JSONArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist

I have an Object ArrayList consist of some variables, I store it in an ArrayList of Object. I Convert it to JSONArray and pass it to a jsp page. How do I display these object in a textarea on a jsp page using javascript

```
public class myObject{
    private String fileName;
    private String filePath;
    private List<String> messsage;

    //Constructor, null constructor and access modifier methods.

}
```

In my Java Controller,

```
ArrayList<myObject> filesContainer = //from source file
JSONArray jsFileList = new JSONArray(fileSources);

ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView();
mnv.addObject("fileList", jsFileList);
mnv.setViewName("forward:Test.jsp");
return mnv;
```

Here in my jsp page i have create a text area:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="display"></textarea>

<script>
    function fileList(){
        <% JSONArray fileList;
        if(request.getAttribute("fileList") != null){
            fileList = (JSONArray) request.getAttribute("fileList"); 

            %>


        <% } %> 
    }
</script>
```

How do i access fileName, filePath in my jsp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I retrieve the data.. Thank you on sharing...

> var x = "<%= j.getString("fileName") %>";

```
function fileList(){
        <% JSONArray fileList;
        if(request.getAttribute("fileList") != null){
            fileList = (JSONArray) request.getAttribute("fileList");%>

            <%
                for(int i=0;i<fileList.length();i++){ %>

                <% JSONObject j = fileList.getJSONObject(i); %>
                var x = "<%= j.getString("fileName") %>";
                document.getElementById("fileSelector").value += x + "\n";

            <% } %>


        <% } %> 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < fileList.length() ; i++ ){
    JSONObject j = fileList.getJSONObject("test");
    System.out.println(j.getString("fileName"));
    System.out.println(j.getString("ms"));
}
```

Look this:
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/json-servlet-example.shtml